# Heirarchical URLs with CPT and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Having a real hard time getting to the bottom of this, all I'm trying to do is create a perfectly logical URL structure for a custom taxonomy.

- I have a CPT: '`knowledgebase`'
- I have a custom taxonomy used by this CPT: '`knowledgebase_topics`'

I want a url that works like so: `domain.tld/knowledgebase/%knowledgebase_topic%`

The closest I've gotten is:

- `domain.tld/topics/%knowledgebase_topic%`

Close but no cigar.

Current taxonomy and CPT code:

```
register_post_type( 'knowledgebase',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(
                'name'  => __( 'Knowledgebase' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Article' )
            ),
        'public'        => true,
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'knowledgebase' ),
        'taxonomies'    => array('knowledgebase_topics'),
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-sos',
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' )
        )
    );

register_taxonomy(
      'knowledgebase_topics',
      'knowledgebase',
      array(
        'labels'       => array('name' => 'Topics' , 'singular_name' => 'Topic', 'add_new_item' => 'Add new topic', 'not_found' => 'No topics found' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite'      => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'slug' => 'topics' ),
        'capabilities' => array( 'edit_terms' => 'manage_categories' )
      )
    );
```

So what trick am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both your `rewrite` arguments, add `'with_front' => false`, then for your taxonomy change `'slug' => 'topics'` to `'slug' => 'knowledgebase'`.

Finally, switch the order of your registration - so that `register_taxonomy` is called first. This will place the taxonomy rewrite rules above the post type rules (otherwise the latter will catch the former, since you have matching slugs).

Flush permalinks (just re-save them in the admin) and you're good to go.

Comment: That did it, thank you! Also helped to explain a couple of the attributes in more detail, the descriptions on the codex left me with more questions!

Comment: To help avoid conflicts with displaying single posts within the CPT I ended up using `'slug' => 'knowledgebase/topics'` which seems to have worked OK. I wouldn't have minded having the post as a child of the category (i.e. section/category/post) - but one challenge at a time!